# How to create a seekbar in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, seekbar

I need to create a seek bar in my blackberry app like in android. all i need to do with it is to just slide it to the right or left to increase and decrease. does seekbar exist in blackberry or is it called as a slider in blackberry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a  SliderScreen:

```
public class SliderScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
    private SliderField slider;
    private HorizontalFieldManager hm;

    public SliderField(){
        slider = new SliderField(
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_thumb_normal.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_progress_normal.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_base_normal.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_thumb_focused.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_progress_focused.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_base_focused.png"), 
            8, 4, 8, 8, FOCUSABLE);

        slider.setChangeListener(this);
        hm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        hm.add(slider);
        setStatus(hm);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        try {
            if (field == slider) {
                int value = slider.getValue();
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and Finally get the SliderField Class and SliderImages From [this BlackBerry Documents](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/SliderField.java)

you can get the seekbar images from [BlackBerry samples](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/tree/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/images/sliders/version2)

Comment: Thanks Pavan. But i get this error saying SliderField cannot be resolved to a type?

Comment: @Mr.Noob you can check my blog for example on your question,there i'm able to create the seekbar.Here is the [example](http://www.javacodeone.blogspot.in/2012/11/blackberry-sliderbarseekbar-creation.html),Let me know again,if you not able to solve your issue..

Comment: Thanks Pavan. I'm a bit new in blackberry.  All i need is to use a sliderField in my app ur example extends the slider with a main screen right? so all I need to do is to just create the slider objects and pass the bitmaps to it isnt it?

Comment: yes,follow the package structure..if you place this statement setStatus(hm);,then slider will be displayed at the bottom of your screen

Answer (score 2):

In the API there's a [`GaugeField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/GaugeField.html) but it's only meant for displaying values, the user can't change it. But you can use the [`AdvancedUiLibrary`](http://docs.blackberry.com/es-es/developers/deliverables/29251/About_the_advanced_UI_library_1626501_11.jsp) which has an `SliderField`. Example [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/es-es/developers/deliverables/29251/Creating_a_slider_1626520_11.jsp).